# How to combine two files into an archive file in Reactor framework?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, zip, flux

Suppose we have several Publishers, each streaming contents of a separate file.

How to combine them into a single Publisher, streaming a ZIP archive containing all those files.

For simplicity, let's use two basic files having names "FileA.txt", "FileB.txt".

```
Flux<DataBuffer> fileA = getFirstFileContents();
Flux<DataBuffer> fileB = getSecondFileContents();

Flux<DataBuffer> zippedFiles = zipMyFiles(fileA, fileB);
```

**What is the conventional (reactive) way to implement `zipMyFiles` function?**